# Patch Bowtie Antenna Design

Tags: antenna

I would appreciate it if someone could help me in designing a patch bowtie antenna.

I would like to know the frequency and the bandwidth in terms of the length, angle and the length and width of the gap. See the following image:

[image: Bow Tie Antenna]

It seems easy but I could not find anything useful on the internet or books.

Comment: It might help if you tell us what frequency you are planning this for.  A quick search of the literature on Patch Bowtie antennas has them used mostly for microwave range applications especially for WLAN uses in the 2.4 GHz and 5GHz bands.  At that frequency, your whole wavelength is on the order of 6cm.

Comment: I plan to use it for frequencies around 600 GHz, but I would like to know what bandwidth I can get with playing with other parameters like angle, L, W, d ot t. Thanks

Comment: Bandwidth at that frequency is essentially unlimited, but this is probably not the right forum to get much information about it.  We are talking wavelengths around 0.0005 meters, that's getting towards IR.

Comment: The research article, "[A Compact Slotted Bowtie Patch Antenna](http://ap-s.ei.tuat.ac.jp/isapx/2009/pdf/1055.pdf)", provides a set of equations you can solve that will provide you with the frequency and bandwidth.

While it focuses on bowtie patch antennas with slots, it does provide some insight into simple bowtie patch antennas, and the references at the end show a number of other resources to provide you with the information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found both of these papers that may help you out.

[Bowtie Microstrip Antenna Design](https://web.archive.org/web/20140304134741/http://library.utem.edu.my/index2.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_view&gid=4754&Itemid=208)

[Methods to Design Microstrip Antennas for 
Modern Applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20140304134859/http://www.intechopen.com/download/get/type/pdfs/id/14714)

Comment: Would you care to spell out their recommendations so as to prevent link rot?

Comment: Here let's just cure that linkrot before it happens.

https://web.archive.org/web/20140304134741/http://library.utem.edu.my/index2.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_view&gid=4754&Itemid=208

https://web.archive.org/web/20140304134859/http://www.intechopen.com/download/get/type/pdfs/id/14714

Comment: Better to cure your linkrot would be to include the most important information from those papers in your awnser.